# How to use android accessibility for global texts?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have some metric units like "kg" and "ml". Talkback reads the letters, and I implemented the contentDescription on every case:

```
when (someText) {
    "kg" -> someText.contentDescription = "kilograms"
    "ml" -> someText.contentDescription = "milliliters"
}
```

This works, but I need to make this global: every kg or ml in the app, needs to be read by Talkback as "kilograms" or "milliliters".

Which is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be set for Talkback on an app level. You could create a utils function and use it throughout the codebase.

Something like:

```
fun TextView.setUnit(unit: String) {
    text = unit
    when (unit) {
        "kg" -> contentDescription = "kilograms"
        "ml" -> contentDescription = "milliliters"
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
textView.setUnit("kg")
```

Another option could be to make a custom view for rendering units that sets content description.